# installation of R package NORMT3 fails on apple M1 pro

Tags: r, apple-m1

I am trying to install the R package NORMT3 on my mac book pro (apple M1 chip) but get the following error.

1. Download via
   wget https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/NORMT3/NORMT3_1.0.4.tar.gz
2. Install via
   R CMD install NORMT3_1.0.4.tar.gz

```
Error:
* installing to library ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library’
* installing *source* package ‘NORMT3’ ...
** package ‘NORMT3’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c IPerfcvec.c -o IPerfcvec.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c IPwofzvec.c -o IPwofzvec.o
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c NORMT3_init.c -o NORMT3_init.o
gfortran -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c toms680-1.f -o toms680-1.o
toms680-1.f:164:72:

  164 |             QLAMBDA = QLAMBDA/H2
      |                                                                        ^
Warning: 'h2' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
toms680-1.f:139:12:

  139 |           H2   = 2.0D0*H
      |            ^
note: 'h2' was declared here
toms680-1.f:164:72:

  164 |             QLAMBDA = QLAMBDA/H2
      |                                                                        ^
Warning: 'qlambda' may be used uninitialized [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
toms680-1.f:146:22:

  146 |         IF (B) QLAMBDA = H2**KAPN
      |                      ^
note: 'qlambda' was declared here
clang -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o NORMT3.so IPerfcvec.o IPwofzvec.o NORMT3_init.o toms680-1.o -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file toms680-1.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-NORMT3/00new/NORMT3/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘NORMT3’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-NORMT3/00new/NORMT3/libs/NORMT3.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-NORMT3/00new/NORMT3/libs/NORMT3.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace (_wofz_)
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/NORMT3’
```

Please let mw know if there is a fix for this. Thanks

Comment: It's trying to build for arm64 but your gfortran installation is x86_64. I don't know how to make it build for x86_64, but the alternative would be to get an arm64 build of gfortran.

Comment: Thanks, can you let me know how to get an arm64 build of gfortran.

Comment: Build it from source?

Answer (score 0):

hello，I have met the same question.

```
clang -arch x86_64 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/opt/R/x86_64/lib -o NORMT3.so IPerfcvec.o IPwofzvec.o NORMT3_init.o toms680-1.o -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/aarch64-apple-darwin22/12.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libquadmath.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/gfortran/lib/libgfortran.dylib, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for macOS-arm64
ld: warning: ignoring file toms680-1.o, building for macOS-x86_64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-arm64
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/00LOCK-NORMT3/00new/NORMT3/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘NORMT3’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/00LOCK-NORMT3/00new/NORMT3/libs/NORMT3.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/00LOCK-NORMT3/00new/NORMT3/libs/NORMT3.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '_wofz_'
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/NORMT3’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/chengtuo/Downloads/NORMT3_1.0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

i fill it through this way.

my mac is M1 chip, and download R with X86.

but i foud my gfortran version was arm. so i download gfortran x86(intel) version. https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases

[enter image description here][1]

```
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.3-x86_64/Resources/library/00LOCK-NORMT3/00new/NORMT3/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** checking absolute paths in shared objects and dynamic libraries
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (NORMT3)
```